# Display Count of User reviews in a product

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a small ASP.NET MVC web application written in C# that allows users to add reviews to products.

Is it possible for me to return a count of how many reviews a user has made for a singular product in a simple display?;

```
'Username' has made X reviews on this product
```

Where X reviews is the number they have made.

I have 3 models: User, Product and Review

A user can have a collection of Products and Reviews
A product can have a collection of Reviews.

I think I am just confused on how I can get a count of reviews made by a specific user. I can get a count of all reviews made, just not individual user numbers on a single product. I can get a list of products for a user, a list of reviews for a product as they only look into a collection of another however this relies on looking for a collection inside a collection which I cannot do.

What I have tried so far -  *It doesn't work because I can't look for a collection in a collection*:

DAO:

```cs
public int UserReviewCount (string UserId, int ProductId, Context context)
{
    Product product = context.Products.Find(ProductId)
    User user = context.Users.Find(UserId)
    return user.product.Reviews.Count(); // Can only do user.Reviews, user.products etc... 
}
```

Service:

```cs
public int UserReviewCount (string UserId, int ProductId)
{
    using (var context = new Context())
    {
        IList<Review> Reviews;
        Reviews = productDAO.GetReviews(id, context);
        return Reviews;
    }
}
```

GetReviews method in DAO:

```cs
public IList<Review> GetReviews(int id, Context context)
{
    Product product = context.Products.Find(id); 
    return product.Reviews.ToList();
}
```

Model definitions - `User` model:

```cs
[Key]
public string UserId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Phone { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

User database definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] 
(
    [UserId]  NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [Name]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Phone]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Email]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Users] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC)
);
```

Review Model:

```cs
[Key]
public int ReviewId { get; set; }
public string Details { get; set; }
public int Rating { get; set; }
```

Review database definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reviews] 
(
    [ReviewId] INT  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Details] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Rating] INT NULL,
    [Product_ProductId] INT NULL,
    [User_UserId] NVARCHAR (128) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Reviews] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ReviewId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Reviews_dbo.Products_Product_ProductId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([Product_ProductId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Products] ([ProductId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Reviews_dbo.Users_User_UserId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([User_UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserId])
);
```

Product model:

```cs
[Key]
public int ProductId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews{ get; set; }
```

Product database definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products] 
(
    [ProductId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [User_UserId]  NVARCHAR (128) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Products] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProductsId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Products_dbo.Users_User_UserId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([User_UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserId])
);
```

Just to note, I also have 2 methods which will add the review to either the user collection or the product collection.

Review to Product collection:

```
public void AddReviewToCollection(Review review, int ProductId, Context context)
{
    context.Products.Find(ProductId).Reviews.Add(review);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Review to User collection:

```cs
public void AddReviewToCollection(Review review, string UserId, Context context)
{
    context.Users.Find(UserId).Reviews.Add(review);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: @Crowcoder Hi, yes, I've used include to switch from lazy loading to eager loading. However how would I use this for my scenario? I can do `context.Users.Include(g => g.Products).Count()` or context.Products.Include(g => g.Reviews).Count() but these will just again count all items in that collection.

Comment: Could I use IQueryable to just write an SQL statement that returns a count of reviewIds? Something like "SELECT COUNT(ReviewId) FROM UserS WHERE ProductId = '1'?

Comment: It seems it would be simpler if a `UserId` was stored with the `Review`, but it appears that is not the case, correct? Does a `Review` have a `ProductId`?

Comment: @RufusL In the review table, there are 2 foreign keys, Product_ProductId and User_UserId. I thought these would be what I used to get the specific users reviews for a product. I.e ReviewIds 3 & 4 rows both have a ProductId of 2 and UserId of 1

Comment: So can't you do `product.Reviews.Count(review => review.UserId == user.Id`, or `user.Reviews.Count(review => review.ProductId == product.Id)`, or `context.Reviews.Where(review => review.UserId == UserId && review.ProductId == ProductId)`?

Comment: @RufusL I thought this was the way however I can't reference the foreign key fields inside the count. I can get to `product.Reviews.Count(review => review.` but then review. wont give me the UserId or ProductId. Is it advisable to edit the post with the model definitions?

Comment: @RufusL I have uploaded the model definitions in case I have set up the foreign keys wrong however I can't see this being the issue.

Comment: @RufusL I have also uploaded 2 methods that I use to add the reviews to their respective collections in case this is what is causing the issue.

Comment: The FKs need to be accessible - you aren't showing them at all above

Comment: @RufusL Sorry can you elaborate? I have uploaded the database definitions aswell as the model code if this is what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
public long UserReviewCount(string UserId, int ProductId, Context context)
{
   Product product = context.Products.Find(ProductId);
   User user = context.Users.Find(UserId);
   return product.Reviews.Count(x => x.UserId == UserId && x.ProductId == ProductId);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding, this is the same issue as the comments above. I can't reference my foreign key fields inside the count. I have uploaded the model definitions as I may have set it up wrong.

Comment: SO if you don't store the product and userId fields in the Review table you can't calculate the count of reviews made by a user on a product. PLs update your model to have the userId and productId in the model.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I have them as foreign keys so in the review table, they do exist as User_UserId and Product_ProductID however the problem is I can't reference them in the count.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the post with the model definitions and also added 2 methods that I use that add the reviews to either user collection or product collection, in case this is also what makes it so I can't reference UserId/ProductId

Comment: I don't understand that if you want to return the number of reviews on a specific product from UserReviewCount method, why don't you use only this:
var res = context.Reviews.Where(x => x.User_UserId == userId && x.Product_ProductId == productId).Count();